# Storing the variables that have been read inside of a block of code

Tags: python, locals

I am trying to store the variables that have been either read or written to inside of code run inside of the exec() function and I do not know what is the best way to do this.

The only approach I can think of is to do something like this:

```
class newDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args):
         dict.__init__(self, args)
         self.accessed_variables = set()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
         val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
         self.accessed_variables.add(key)
         return val

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
         self.accessed_variables.add(key)
         dict.__setitem__(self, key,value)

    def get_variables(self):
         return self.accessed_variables

local_env = newDict()
global_env = newDict()
code = """ """
exec(code, global_env, local_env)
print(local_env.get_variables)
```

Comment: I see no reason to down-vote this question. The task is clear, own effort is shown, and, in my opinion, that's likely the most sensible way to do that. Is that for some debugging/profiling?

Comment: it is used to capture the state of the interpreter at a given moment in time.